# Angular y Django. Error de seguridad al acceder a imágenes

Tags: angular, django, html2canvas

Estoy trabajando con Angular y Django.

En angular estoy generando reportes con `jspdf` y `html2canvas`, para esto estoy cargando imágenes almacenadas en Django y al momento de querer generar el pdf me genera el error:

> "SecurityError: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported"

En Django tengo agregado `corsheaders` y dado los permisos par poder acceder desde Angular:

```
DEBUG = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost', '127.0.0.1']

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = False

CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [
'http://localhost:4200',
]

CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = list(default_methods) + [
'POKE',
]

CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = list(default_headers) + [
'my-custom-header',
]
```

La función en Angular para generar el pdf:

```
pdf () {
html2canvas(document.querySelector("#content"), {allowTaint : 
true}).then(canvas => {

var img=new Image(); img.crossOrigin="anonymous"
img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
var doc = new jsPDF();
doc.addImage(img, 'JPEG', 0, 10);
doc.save('test.pdf');
});
}
```

Revisando páginas sugerían agregar el `crossOrigin="anonymous"` pero esto no me ha funcionado

Comment: Puedes [editar tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/328897/edit) cambiando las imágenes y pegando el código. Además cambiando el título que está en inglés por algo que describa mejor el problema y pasando el error en el cuerpo de la pregunta, o mejor agregando la pila entera de errores. y explicando en qué parte tuviste el problema.

Comment: Bienvenido @user155013. Tu pregunta tiene buena pinta. Sin embargo, considere [edit] y reemplazar las imágenes por el código para que podamos copiarlo y probarlo para poder ayudarte. Además, te invito a realizar un [tour] para que ganes tu primera medalla. Si se te dificulta colocar el código aquí puede consultar [Ayuda de edición de Markdown](https://es.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-reply).

Comment: Listo, espero se entienda mejor